# Move or duplicate association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, cloning

I have a polymorphic association called ListedProduct.
This is a record with some associations like product, price and specifications.

It's polymorphic because it can be associated to a Cart or an Order.

Now the problem is that I need to move, or duplicate it from the Cart to the order.

**So for example:**

A Cart has some listed_products and the user wants to order these.

Now they need to be associated to a new order instead of the cart.

**Possibilities:**

Copying all the attributes by hand. This doesn't feel right.

Changing the polymorphic columns to the new type and ID. Problem: Order isn't saved yet and has no ID.

I bet there is some other way, I just don't know what to look for..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need all time you can use the below keyword to refer to another objects

```
delegate
alias_method
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't really see how this would help me out.. Can you be more specific?